# Equality with Java generics: the subclass equals isn't called

Tags: java

I've got a `Node<T>` with an `equals()` method:

```
public boolean equals(Node<T> other) {
    if (this == other)
        return true;
    if (other == null)
        return false;
    if (!obj.getClass().equals(other.getObject().getClass()))
        return false;

    return obj.equals(other.getObject());
}
```

I only care if the object held in my node is equal to the object held in the other node (because two equal objects can be held in different positions in my list).

The object I'm holding is a `Token`. The `Token.equals()` method works while my `Node.equals()` method does not:

```
public class TokenEqualityTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Token t = new Token(0);
        Token q = new Token(0);
        System.out.println("t.equals(q): " + t.equals(q));

        Node<Token> tnode = new Node<Token>(null, null, t);
        Node<Token> qnode = new Node<Token>(null, null, q);
        System.out.println("tnode.equals(qnode): " + tnode.equals(qnode));
    }
}
```

which prints:

```
t.equals(q): true
tnode.equals(qnode): false
```

If I put a breakpoint at `Token.equals()` and run the eclipse debugger, my code stops once (at `t.equals(q)`). This indicates that `Node<Token>.equals()` does *not* call `Token.equals`, and I have verified that the debugger does step through the line `return obj.equals(other.getObject());`.

#### Why doesn't my `Node.equals` ever call `Token.equals` when I've declared a `Node<Token>`?

Comment: You're using `equals(Node<T> other)` while the correct overload from the base class should be `equals(Object other)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that you didn't override the base `equals()` method in `Token`, just like you didn't in `Node`.

You need to declare it as `equals(Object)`.

Add the `@Override` annotation to catch that.

Answer (score 3):

Your `equals` method should have the following signature:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

And when you override `equals` method, you should override `hashCode` method, too. This is contract that all object should follow.

For prevent this kind of mistake, it would be better to add `@Override` annotation.

Or you can use [lombok](http://projectlombok.org) to simplify defining `equals` and `hashCode` methods by [`@EqualsAndHashCode`](http://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html) annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The equals method must take an `Object` type as a parameter in order to override the parent class equals method. It should also return a primitive `boolean` type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override equals method this way:

```
@Override
  public boolean equals(Object object) {

    // add your logic here
  }
```

Also you need to override hashCode method. This is the contract:

```
 @Override
  public int hashCode() {
  return hashCode;
}
```